# Subadditivity of Lebesgue inner measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, outer-measure

Im in a trouble. I want to prove this proposition:

Let $A,B \subseteq \Re^n $ such that $d(A,B)>0$.
Then, $ m_*(A\cup B) \le m_*(A) + m_*(B)  $
.
Where  $m_*$ is the Lebesgue inner measure.

I don't know if this lemma is true. But it would help me if it were.
Thank you! $<2+1$

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is true.

Recall that 
$$m_{*}(A) = \sup_{U\subset A, U \textrm{meas}} m(U)= \sup_{K\subset A, K \textrm{compact}}m(K) $$

Let $d = d(A,B)$.  Consider $A_1 = \{x \ | d(x,A) \le \frac{d}{3}\}$, $B_1= \{x \ | d(x,B) \le \frac{d}{3}\}$. We have $A_1$, $B_1$ closed and disjoint, $A\subset A_1$, $B\subset B_1$. This measurable separation of $A$, $B$ is all we need.

Take $U\subset A\cup B$, $U$ measurable. We have $U\cap A_1 \subset A$, $U\cap B_1 \subset B$ and $U = (U\cap A_1) \cup U\cap B_1 $ a partition of $U$.

We have 
$$m(U) = m(U\cap A_1) + m(U \cap B_1) \le m_{*}(A) + m_{*}(B)$$

Now take the supremum over all $U$ measurable, $U\subset A\cup B$.

Note that in general for $A$, $B$ disjoint we have 
$$m_{*}(A)+m_{*}(B) \le m_*(A\cup B)$$
Therefore, if $A$, $B$ are moreover separated, we have equality.

Comment: Thank you so much <3 my teacher are sleeping and she doesnt reply me hahhaa, Thanks again!!

Comment: @Valentín Andrada:  No worries.... the equality is also true for the exterior measure, with a similar proof.